# How to set the button clickable unclickable via android xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button

Is it possible to make the button clickable/unclickable based on flag condition via android xml
like this as specified below

```
   android:clickable="@{viewModel.isTodayDate() ? false:true}"
```

It is not working is there any way to achieve it.Even `android:clickable="false" is not working`

Comment: Why not try to disable it? A disabled button is not clickable. Or you can't disable it for some reason?

Comment: Add more code of `ViewModel` like as `isTodayDate` function for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the attribute you're looking for is `enabled`

```
<Button
  android:enabled="@{isTodayDate ? true : false}"
/>
```